# Gridview and objectDatasource

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I am trying to bind this to a gridview..

```
 var source = from p in allComments
                 select new { p.Img, p.Name, p.Comment };
    GridView1.DataSource = source;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

all Comments has 
But it wont bind cause my gridview allows paging. I read a bit about that problem and i found to bind the gridview ,, i could use ObjectDataSource... And return a dataset to bind to the gridview..

I have got this mark up of the gridview (only part of the mark up):

```
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="500px" />
                     <ItemStyle Width="500px" Height="100px" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("Comment") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
                      <ItemStyle Width="100px" Height="100px" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgName" runat="server"  imageUrl='<%# Bind("Img") %>'></asp:Image><br />
                        <asp:Hyperlink ID="hyperLink" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' ></asp:Hyperlink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

What do you think..Should I use objectdataSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ObjectDataSource`, then `Paging and Sorting` will automatically work. I would recommend you to use the ObjectDataSource as it has many other features that you can use, like `caching` etc...
Please check this link [Displaying Data With the ObjectDataSource](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/displaying-data-with-the-objectdatasource-cs)

Check out this for more about ObjectDataSource http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx